# svn: Not authorized to open root of edit operation

Tags: svn, centos

We have a very odd problem here with SVN. Let me first explain the (server) situation. We have development server (CentOs 5.5) with a ordinary LAMP stack, subversion and Trac configured. In this server we have several repositories where we develop PHP application.

Now the point is that checking a project out (svn co) with our local Ubuntu machines is not really a problem and neither is committing etc.

On the development server checking out/exporting is becoming a problem and we get the error: 
svn: Not authorized to open root of edit operation

I have searched the internet for this error and I get a lot of pages telling me we have to set-up 'anon-access=none' in our svnserve.conf. In our case this is not the problem because anon-access is already set to 'none'. Still that doesn't solve this issue.

The weird thing is that if we checkout with a file url instead of a http url, so like: svn co file:///var/svn/etc it actually works while with a url it doesn't: https://www.url.ext/svn/project/trunk

Has anybody a clue? Or can say what I should look for? SVN is accessed thru davsvn under HTTPS with a self-signed certificate, but that doesn't seem the problem to me cause working from our local machines is okay.

Comment: Are you getting anything in your web server error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to apoligize I made a mistake, on the webroot of the server was a htaccess file with order deny, allow and the ipaddress of the servers where I tried to checkout wern't in the list of allowed ipaddresses. I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0):

for me the following helped, in my "authz" file I had:

```
[/]
* =
```

I changed it to:

```
[/]
* = r
```