# Importing read-only Subversion to Git blocked by "Read access denied for root of edit"

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, svn2git

I am trying to import code from a semi-public Subversion repository into my own Git repo.  [The Subversion repo access is explained here](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~harmony/) (enable JavaScript to read; look under the "[Download]" link).

I have tried to use `git svn clone` manually as well as via the [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) utility.  Either way, I keep running into the same error as shown below.

I can verify that I have access to the Subversion repo: `svn co svn+ssh://harmony@eniac.seas.upenn.edu/trunk` works.

Help!

```
$ svn2git svn+ssh://harmony@eniac.seas.upenn.edu -v
Running command: git svn init --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --trunk=trunk --tags=tags --branches=branches svn+ssh://harmony@eniac.seas.upenn.edu
Running command: git svn fetch
Read access denied for root of edit: Not authorized to open root of edit operation at /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.5.3/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 290

command failed:
2>&1 git svn fetch
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070296/svn-not-authorized-to-open-root-of-edit-operation

Comment: I'm not sure that applies to my situation because I am a guest of the Subversion repo; I do not have administrative control over it to fix its access permissions. What I need is a client-side workaround, if such a thing is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the clone or svn2git process work I am pretty sure you are stuck with one of the two solutions of:

**In svnserve.conf setting:**

`anon-access = read` To: `anon-access = none`

**Or if it is served via Apache using the Apache SVN module in the Authz file linked in the comment making the change:**

```
[/]
* =
```

To:

```
[/]
* = r
```

**All of that said:**

Given that the above is a non-solution to your problem if you are unable to have the server configured properly to allow you to do this you could see if you have any better luck with the svnsync command:

- [Steps to sync repo locally](http://aligorith.blogspot.ca/2011/10/svn-tip-making-local-copy-of-svn.html)
- [Original version of the same instructions](http://iacoware.wordpress.com/2009/10/02/howto-use-svnsync-to-mirror-a-repository-on-windows/)

You could then use your local SVN to create your git repo. Assuming your intent is to be able to push changes back to the original SVN source, *I think* this will not require the needed configuration discussed above for the initial clone, and you would be able to get it working from this point... This entire recommendation is based on a chain of "maybes", so hopefully someone else has a better solution if you really need to do this and cannot have the configuration of the server altered.

Comment: Interacting with the Subversion repo is not necessary. In fact, I am operating under the assumption that it's been abandoned. All I want to do is preserve its history in a Git repo.

Comment: Did you have any luck with svnsync then?

Comment: I am actually working on it at this very moment, so no worries. :-) I'll follow up here. *Update:* It's chugging away now. I have a good feeling about this.

Comment: So this ended up being a two-step process as you described: (1) creating a mirror of the Subversion repo using svnsync, then (2) importing the local mirror to a Git repo using svn2git. A nice side benefit is that I could try the import multiple times and not have to waste bandwidth doing it. The instructions at the links you gave me were Windows-specific, but they were easy enough to adapt. So thanks! Don't spend those 50 reps all in one place. ;-)